# Using the accounting.FormatMoney with negative values, Accounting.js

Tags: javascript, accounting.js

I have a question about the use of accountingMoney.FormatMoney in Accounting.js.  If I am passing a negative value into a field in this format:

$('#newModFund4587').val(accounting.formatMoney(fund4587));

NewModFund4587 is a text box that can be modifiable.  The value in fund4587 is negative.   When I display the field it is showing the value as negative.  But when I try to modify the text box or even just tab out of the field it changes to a positive value.  When you use FormatMoney, is a negative value still stored as a negative or is converted to positive and formatted to show as negative.

**Edit**:  I did find something that maybe explains this situation.  When I take a new field and put in a negative amount, the value would show as **'-100.00'**.  Then I changed the value to use the FormatMoney the value would convert to **'$-100.00'**.   When I go back to that field and try to change it or even tab around it that is where it changes always to a positive value.

If you have a field that begins with a '$' does it assume that it will always be positive?  If a field began with '-$' would it treat it as negative?

Thanks